# How to remove the Privacy - Terms from Google recaptcha?

Tags: php, recaptcha

How can I change or hide Privacy & Terms text/link in Google new reCAPTCHA. I've tried with css and jquery and both are not working.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @kerbholz In my Application google recaptcha is there but its client requirement to remove privacy and term from google recaptcha iframe. so is it possible to remove??

Comment: Not to use it if not OK with its Terms I guess?

Comment: Using ReCaptcha with no agreement to google Terms and Privacy is NOT logical at all ! NO you can't remove it

Comment: Tidy up for presentation

Comment: Rick is really asking about the fixed positioned "banner" Google has added that has started appearing. Typical of word press. caiovisk has fixed this in his post.

Answer (score 9):

> Changing/removing or hiding the privacy policy and terms is against
>   the terms set by Google and agreed by you when you generated the API
>   Key.

But for testing or debugging purposes you can hide the badge through the CSS, like below:

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
    left: -500px !important;
    right: initial !important;
}
```

or

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. I bet this is what Rick was after.

Answer (score 9):

From Google's documentation:

> You are allowed to hide the badge as long as you include the reCAPTCHA branding visibly in >the user flow. Please include the following text:
>
> This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
>      [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) and
>      [Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms) apply.

[image: example]

Source: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can remove the badge by adding following lines in your CSS file

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
     visibility: collapse
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ReCaptcha runs in it's own iframe and it would be really bad if you from the host container could change anything -in- that iframe. So No - this is not possible. Besides the point that changing/removing or hiding the privacy policy and terms is against the terms set by Google.

Comment: Sorry but the badge is not in the iFrame, caiovisk has resolved. Rick is unclear explaining the issue.